# ASPNET Core Options Binding does not populate dictionary key/value pair

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, binding

I have the following JSON configuration

```
"Configurations": {
    "KeyA": {
      "Ids": []
    },
    "KeyB": {
      "Ids": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    "KeyC": {
      "Ids": [1, 2, 3],
      "OptionalData": "asdf"
    }

}
```

This is then read into the following object

```
public class AppConfiguration
{
    public Dictionary<ConfigType, ConfigurationData> Configurations {get; set;} = new Dictionary<ConfigType, ConfigurationData>();
}

public class ConfigurationData
{
    public HashSet<int> Ids {get;set;} = new HashSet<int>();

    public string OptionalData = "";
}

public Enum ConfigType
{
    KeyA = 1,
    KeyB = 2,
    KeyC = 3
}
```

I then bind this in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method using

```
services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(this.Configuration);
```

However, I notied that the configuration binding produces my `AppConfiguration`'s dictionary with only the `KeyB` and `KeyC` keys, **skipping `KeyA`, because its `Ids` array is empty**. I read up on the behaviour of the configuration binding online, but as far as I saw it should bind the Ids to null, but here it just does not generate a key value pair in the dictionary altogether.

I tried removing the "Ids" property, leaving my config like `"KeyA": {}"`, but this still did not work. The only way I can get it to parse is if I put in some numbers in the array, but this obviously not what I want.

I would like to know if there is anyway I can bind such a key-value pair, where I don't have any Ids in my array. This seems like it should be somehow supported out of the box, but I'm not sure why it's not working and how could I resolve it, without implementing some hacky custom configuration loader/binder.

Comment: Hi @Kobek, I think you need refer to this github issue:https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/864. It seems to be impossible to meet you requirement without implementing custom binder.

Comment: I don't believe this is the same issue though. Its not a string that I'm having an issue with :(

I have defined a dictionary with keys and their values, and one of the values happens to contain an empty array. I don't think it makes sense that this should not be filled. I do believe it is a bug, but it seems it's not the one reported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, I managed to solve this by setting my array to null, instead of an empty array like so.

```
"Configurations": {
    "KeyA": {
      "Ids": null
    }
}
```